# What do you call the alternate of a negation statement?

Tags: logic

Consider the original statement: all politicians lie.

The negation of the statement is: there exist some politicians that don't lie.

But what about the following: all politicians don't lie. Is there a word for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classical logic, "All politicians lie" is the Universal Affirmative. If P is the set of politicians and L the set of liars, then we can write it as "All P is L".

"All politicians don't lie" is more commonly expressed in this tradition of logic as "No politicians lie". This is the Universal Negative, "No P is L".

These two statements are contraries, i.e. "All politicians lie" is contrary to "All politicians don't lie".

Answer (score -1):

There is no link between the two statements "all politicians lie" and "all politicians don't lie", and so therefore there is no word that can be used to describe the relationship between them

You are right when you say that "there exist some politicians that don't lie" is a negation of the first statement, but the statement "all politicians don't lie" is a completely different statement in and of itself. The negation to this statement would be "There exists some politician that does lie".

Hope that makes sense!